# sankey plot from plotly package is blank, no error or warning

Tags: r, plotly, sankey-diagram

I tried to generate the sankey plot by plotly package, however there is a no error or warning but the graph is blank, could you please let me know the reason

I attached the data which I used, the data_long and nodes

I am not sure what is the reason, please help me with the reason and solution to generate the plot

data_long dataset

```r
data_long <- structure(list(target = c("APPLICATION SITE DERMATITIS", "APPLICATION SITE DERMATITIS", 
"APPLICATION SITE DERMATITIS", "APPLICATION SITE ERYTHEMA", "APPLICATION SITE ERYTHEMA", 
"APPLICATION SITE ERYTHEMA", "APPLICATION SITE IRRITATION", "APPLICATION SITE IRRITATION", 
"APPLICATION SITE IRRITATION", "APPLICATION SITE PERSPIRATION", 
"APPLICATION SITE PRURITUS", "APPLICATION SITE PRURITUS", "APPLICATION SITE PRURITUS", 
"APPLICATION SITE VESICLES", "ASTHENIA", "CHEST PAIN", "FATIGUE", 
"FATIGUE", "OEDEMA PERIPHERAL", "MILD", "MILD", "MODERATE", "MILD", 
"MODERATE", "MILD", "MILD", "MODERATE", "MODERATE", "MODERATE", 
"MILD", "MILD", "MILD", "NONE", "POSSIBLE", "PROBABLE", "REMOTE", 
"PROBABLE", "REMOTE", "N", "N", "N", "N"), source = c("Placebo", 
"Xanomeline High Dose", "Xanomeline Low Dose", "Placebo", "Xanomeline High Dose", 
"Xanomeline Low Dose", "Placebo", "Xanomeline High Dose", "Xanomeline Low Dose", 
"Xanomeline High Dose", "Placebo", "Xanomeline High Dose", "Xanomeline Low Dose", 
"Xanomeline Low Dose", "Xanomeline High Dose", "Xanomeline High Dose", 
"Xanomeline High Dose", "Xanomeline Low Dose", "Xanomeline High Dose", 
"APPLICATION SITE DERMATITIS", "APPLICATION SITE ERYTHEMA", "APPLICATION SITE ERYTHEMA", 
"APPLICATION SITE IRRITATION", "APPLICATION SITE IRRITATION", 
"APPLICATION SITE PERSPIRATION", "APPLICATION SITE PRURITUS", 
"APPLICATION SITE PRURITUS", "APPLICATION SITE VESICLES", "ASTHENIA", 
"CHEST PAIN", "FATIGUE", "OEDEMA PERIPHERAL", "MILD", "MILD", 
"MILD", "MILD", "MODERATE", "MODERATE", "NONE", "POSSIBLE", "PROBABLE", 
"REMOTE"), value = c(4L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 
1L, 3L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 10L, 11L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 
9L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 10L, 26L, 2L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 10L, 
32L, 3L), IDsource = c(0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 1, 2, 
2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 
13, 13, 13, 14, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18), IDtarget = c(3, 3, 3, 4, 
4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 7, 7, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 11, 12, 13, 13, 14, 
13, 14, 13, 13, 14, 14, 14, 13, 13, 13, 15, 16, 17, 18, 17, 18, 
19, 19, 19, 19)), row.names = c(NA, -42L), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), groups = structure(list(target = c("APPLICATION SITE DERMATITIS", 
"APPLICATION SITE DERMATITIS", "APPLICATION SITE DERMATITIS", 
"APPLICATION SITE ERYTHEMA", "APPLICATION SITE ERYTHEMA", "APPLICATION SITE ERYTHEMA", 
"APPLICATION SITE IRRITATION", "APPLICATION SITE IRRITATION", 
"APPLICATION SITE IRRITATION", "APPLICATION SITE PERSPIRATION", 
"APPLICATION SITE PRURITUS", "APPLICATION SITE PRURITUS", "APPLICATION SITE PRURITUS", 
"APPLICATION SITE VESICLES", "ASTHENIA", "CHEST PAIN", "FATIGUE", 
"FATIGUE", "MILD", "MILD", "MILD", "MILD", "MILD", "MILD", "MILD", 
"MILD", "MODERATE", "MODERATE", "MODERATE", "MODERATE", "MODERATE", 
"N", "N", "N", "N", "NONE", "OEDEMA PERIPHERAL", "POSSIBLE", 
"PROBABLE", "PROBABLE", "REMOTE", "REMOTE"), source = c("Placebo", 
"Xanomeline High Dose", "Xanomeline Low Dose", "Placebo", "Xanomeline High Dose", 
"Xanomeline Low Dose", "Placebo", "Xanomeline High Dose", "Xanomeline Low Dose", 
"Xanomeline High Dose", "Placebo", "Xanomeline High Dose", "Xanomeline Low Dose", 
"Xanomeline Low Dose", "Xanomeline High Dose", "Xanomeline High Dose", 
"Xanomeline High Dose", "Xanomeline Low Dose", "APPLICATION SITE DERMATITIS", 
"APPLICATION SITE ERYTHEMA", "APPLICATION SITE IRRITATION", "APPLICATION SITE PERSPIRATION", 
"APPLICATION SITE PRURITUS", "CHEST PAIN", "FATIGUE", "OEDEMA PERIPHERAL", 
"APPLICATION SITE ERYTHEMA", "APPLICATION SITE IRRITATION", "APPLICATION SITE PRURITUS", 
"APPLICATION SITE VESICLES", "ASTHENIA", "NONE", "POSSIBLE", 
"PROBABLE", "REMOTE", "MILD", "Xanomeline High Dose", "MILD", 
"MILD", "MODERATE", "MILD", "MODERATE"), .rows = structure(list(
    1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 
    15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 20L, 21L, 23L, 25L, 26L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 
    22L, 24L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 33L, 19L, 34L, 
    35L, 37L, 36L, 38L), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
"vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -42L), .drop = TRUE))
```

nodes dataset

```r
nodes <- structure(list(name = c("Placebo", "Xanomeline High Dose", "Xanomeline Low Dose", 
"APPLICATION SITE DERMATITIS", "APPLICATION SITE ERYTHEMA", "APPLICATION SITE IRRITATION", 
"APPLICATION SITE PERSPIRATION", "APPLICATION SITE PRURITUS", 
"APPLICATION SITE VESICLES", "ASTHENIA", "CHEST PAIN", "FATIGUE", 
"OEDEMA PERIPHERAL", "MILD", "MODERATE", "NONE", "POSSIBLE", 
"PROBABLE", "REMOTE", "N")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-20L))
```

#plotly

```r
fig <- plot_ly(
    type = "sankey",
    domain = list(
      x =  c(0,1),
      y =  c(0,1)
    ),
    orientation = "h",
    valueformat = ".0f",
    valuesuffix = "TWh",

    node = list(
      label = nodes$name,
      pad = 15,
      thickness = 15,
      line = list(
        color = "black",
        width = 0.5
      )
    ),

    link = list(
      source = data_long$source,
      target = data_long$target,
      value =  data_long$value 
    )
  ) 
fig <- fig %>% layout(
    title = "aesoc",
    font = list(
      size = 10
    ),
    xaxis = list(showgrid = F, zeroline = F),
    yaxis = list(showgrid = F, zeroline = F)
)

fig
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the source and target `ID` columns from your dataset:

```r
library(plotly)

fig <- plot_ly(
  type = "sankey",
  domain = list(
    x =  c(0, 1),
    y =  c(0, 1)
  ),
  orientation = "h",
  valueformat = ".0f",
  valuesuffix = "TWh",
  node = list(
    label = nodes$name,
    pad = 15,
    thickness = 15,
    line = list(
      color = "black",
      width = 0.5
    )
  ),
  link = list(
    source = data_long$IDsource,
    target = data_long$IDtarget,
    value =  data_long$value
  )
)

fig %>% layout(
  title = "aesoc",
  font = list(
    size = 10
  ),
  xaxis = list(showgrid = F, zeroline = F),
  yaxis = list(showgrid = F, zeroline = F)
)
```

[image]